# Why does this nested sum appear to sleep between iterations?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, summation

I have a weird performance problem in a nested sum, which I've reduced to the following test case:

```
testTab = Table[1.`20, {i, 188}, {j, 301}, {k, 20}];
test[] := Sum[testTab[[1, 1, 1]] Sum[testTab[[1, 1, 1]], {n, 1, 250}], {m, 1, 10}]
Monitor[test[], {n, m}]
```

Here the output from `Monitor` is `{n, 1}` for a second, then it changes to `{n, 2}`, and so on until I get the result of `2500.0000000000000000`. Obviously, table accesses shouldn't be *that* slow.

Even more interestingly, if I change the summation limit of the inner sum from `250` to `249` or smaller, I don't get this slowdown, the result appears almost instantly. I can even make table dimensions way larger, but this 250→249 transition still results in drastic performance difference.

What's happening here? Is it a bug?

I'm using Mathematica "*11.1.0 for Linux x86 (32-bit) (March 13, 2017)*", but this problem also happens on "*9.0 for Linux x86 (32-bit) (November 20, 2012)*" and on "*11.0.1 for Linux ARM (32-bit) (January 17, 2017)*" (Raspberry Pi 3).

Comment: Same behavior in M8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that Mathematica tries to compile the code for sufficiently long `Table`s, `Sum`s, and `Product`s. The outer sum has 10 summands. That's too few. But starting the inner sum with 250 or more summands implies a compilation. 250 is the default value of the suboption `"SumCompileLength"` of the system option `"CompileOptions"`:

```
"SumCompileLength" /. ("CompileOptions" /. SystemOptions[])
```

> 250

This compilation is done for each iteration of the outer `Sum` and induces some overhead. This is why it is a good idea to merge multiple sums into a single instance of `Sum` like this:

```
test2[] := 
 Sum[testTab[[1, 1, 1]] testTab[[1, 1, 1]], {n, 1, 250}, {m, 1, 10}]
```

Moreover, trying to use matrix-vector producs or `Total` may be even more efficient. Needless to say that nothing will beat `testTab[[1, 1, 1]] 250 10` in this case.

Comment: Well of course nothing will beat it, I've already mentioned that it's a [reduced test case](http://sscce.org/). Anyway, is there any means of making `SumCompileLength` way higher to avoid hitting this?

Comment: Yes, for example `SetSystemOptions[
 "CompileOptions" -> {"SumCompileLength" -> \[Infinity]}]`. Use at your own risk.